# How often does KeyListener check keyboard input? (Java GUI)

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, keylistener

I am coding a program whose functions include one that checks whether the user input is one of the arrow keys and moves an on-screen sprite accordingly.

I am using the KeyListener interface for an inner class I call ArrowListener. Currently, I have code in the keyPressed() that moves the sprite on the screen.

I am wondering how often my ArrowListener class checks for keyboard input, because I have another method in the larger component class that calls repaint() every 100 milliseconds. If the KeyListener class checks user input more or less often than this, I will change the repaint frequency as well.

**EDIT:**

I realized that KeyListener doesn't check/poll the keyboard for inputs regularly, but processes interrupts from the keyboard. Still, if I were to hold down a key on the keyboard for, say, 5 seconds, how many interrupts would KeyListener process?

Comment: This is the way the OS works, the delay between the first key press and the second is always delayed, the other key events follow with a smaller delay, there's nothing you can do to change the way this works - BUT, instead of monitoring the key state, you set a flag (or series of flags) which indicate which keys are currently active.  In your case, I might be tempted to use some kind of `Stack` and add "pressed" and "released" actions to it, then in your loop, you could pop off as many actions as you like and process them any way you want - but for a 10th of second, not sure it's worth it

Comment: It doesn't poll. It receives events.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was mistaken; what you're looking for are [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html); these allow you to execute an `ActionListener` only once when a key is pressed.

Comment: I see, so KeyListener takes in an interrupt instead of polls the keyboard. Still, when I press, say, the UP arrow key and hold it there for 5 seconds, how many interrupts would occur?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I tried this on my program (i.e. holding down the UP arrow key for five seconds) and the sprite moved more than once. It kept moving up until I released the UP arrow key.

Comment: I've edited my post with what you should use instead of `KeyListener` if you only want to handle an action when a button is pressed once.